# Are there sources of email marketing data available?

Tags: email, data

Are sources of email marketing data available to the public?

I would like to see email marketing data to see what kind of content a business sends out, the frequency of sending, the number of people emailed, especially the resulting open rates and click through rates.

Are businesses willing to share data on their previous email marketing campaigns without divulging their contact list? I would like to use this data to create an application to help businesses create better newsletters by using this data as a benchmark, basically sharing what works and what doesn't for each industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you're looking at aggregated data, as most people don't want their stats to be seen. The best free sources i've found for this kind of information are [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/resources/), [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/), and [Litmus](http://litmus.com). [Email Marketing Reports](http://www.email-marketing-reports.com/) can also have useful stuff.

A lot of them have breakdown by industry.

There is definitely a lot of this information out there, it still requires a lot of sifting through.

Comment: Thanks Anthonyg, Thanks for those links, they are great sites, I visit those often for information. 

I'd love to see if there are businesses themselves willing to share their historical data too.